# WriteBinaryToFile - Exception occurred Access to the path '<PATH_TO_LIVE_FOLDER>' is denied

Tags: web8, content-delivery

We are getting below error in our Web 8 Application::

```
DefaultLogger          WriteBinaryToFile  - Exception occurred Access to the path 'D:\inetpub\wwwroot\<LIVE_SITE_NAME>\BinaryData\en\media\annual_report_2018_tcm7-6567.pdf' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at DD4T.Factories.BinaryFactory.WriteBinaryToFile(Byte[] bytes, String physicalPath, Dimensions dimensions) in C:\projects\dd4t-core\source\DD4T.Factories\BinaryFactory.cs:line 350
```

All errors have below same Line:

C:\projects\dd4t-core\source\DD4T.Factories\BinaryFactory.cs:line 350

Comment: If it helps, when running in IIS; the application pool owner should have write permissions to the BinaryData folder.

Answer (score 5):

Yes,

it looks like your security is not properly set, so you don't have write permissions for this folder. Please check that your App has write permissions for it.